# Documenting Prototype Extension Functions with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, gulp, jsdoc

I have the following bit of code:

```
/** @module Array */

/**
 * Returns this model's attributes as...
 *
 * @memberof Array.prototype
 * @function
 * @name each
**/
Array.prototype.each = function( callback ) {

    var context = this;

    for( var i = 0; i < context.length; i++ ) {
        callback( context[ i ] );
    }

}
```

When I document this with JSDoc, I get: 
[image]

Why? I am using JSDoc on Gulp.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?  I am having the same problem, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't able to; the native interface doesn't support this. I ended up writing a wrapper for JSDoc which does this. A simple, straight-forward implementation was to use the base-level (globally available) objects, and then define their prototypes. A simple hack, but works nonetheless.

Comment: What it your purpose? You did not write an expected result. Seems like you should edit the answer. But as I can guess you expect `#each` to be documented. For this just add `/** @class Array */` instead of `/** @module Array */`. And you also can remove all tags from `#each`.

Comment: @FreeLightman, it should be evident by the point of JSDoc what the expected output is. There is no answer, marked or otherwise, for this question since this is something every one is/was experiencing. `/** @class **/` is for the ES6-specific class declaration. This was back when we used the `prototype` property.

Comment: @weirdpanda What is evident? For getting help at first you need to write what you expect. This is required for this site. As I know module can only have private and static vars. They can not have instance methods because they are far from instance. Only classes can have instances. So what is your source of information which points that `@class` is ES6-specific? As I read from jsdoc docs it is quite different. And what is downsides with `prototype` in case you choose `@class`?  As I see now all your 3 tags from `each` could me omitted with `@class`.

Comment: JSDoc is the source of information. And I am fully aware about the rules of this website. That was a general questions for which the output should be understood by any one in the business.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as the original poster, but I was extending the `JSON` global with `copy()` and `equals()` methods.

(Since there is some debate in the comments above, I will clarify:  When I say "having the same problem," I mean that the JSDoc comments I placed before the `JSON.copy()` and `JSON.equals()` methods did not appear anywhere in my generated documentation, which was a problem not only because that documentation was lost, but also because no other documentation could link to the `JSON.copy()` or `JSON.equals()` methods.)

Following FreeLightman's suggestion in the comments above, to simply add the following line, solves the problem for me.

```js
/** @class JSON */
```

And by "solves the problem," I mean that there is now a page in my generated documentation that is specifically for the JSON object, and it contains the desired documentation for the `copy()` and `equals()` members, and I can link to those members from elsewhere in my documentation.

Since this is many years after the original question, I will point out that I'm using JSDoc version 6.14.12.

Comment: I now prefer `/** @namespace JSON */` instead.